# Heroku: running a MongoDB and Flask site, defined with Docker-Compose

Tags: deployment, heroku, cloud, docker

I have a docker image that I've made using a single `docker-compose.yml`. It is a very simple Flask and MongoDB site, defined as such:

```
version: '3'
services:
    website:
        build: .
        command: python -u app.py
        ports:
            - "1234:5678"
        volumes:
            - .:/store
        depends_on:
          - database
        networks:
          - eth0
    database:
        image: mongo:latest
        networks:
          - eth0

networks:
  eth0:
    driver: bridge
```

There is only a single docker file, which is for the image, `website`. This image expects to be running a flask server indefinitely and is based on Ubuntu. How can I run this in Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem this is not possible. Note Heroku support says to go to StackExchange, so this is now the official answer.

Individual channels have advised me that IBM, Microsoft, or Amazon, may offer a working alternative, but Heroku is not.